# How to get the nth element in a list of paired tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a=[((a1,a2),(b1,b2)),((c1,c2),(d1,d2))]
```

In this code, how would I access just the values of a1,b1,c1 and d1? I feel like like this may be an unintuitive way of doing what I'd like, but I would like to know if this is possible. When I try to type say something like

```
a[0]
```

then it will return

```
((a1,a2),(b1,b2))
```

which is not what I want.

I'd like to return something like

```
answer_list=[(a1,b1),(c1,d1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using list comprehension you could simply do:

```
answerlist = [i[0] for j in a for i in j]
```

randlet's answer shows the logic broken out

Comment: To further my question, how would I then pair these up into a new list of tuples?

So,

    answerlist= [(a1,b1),(c1,d1)]

Comment: Given a flat list, you can pair it with `zip(l[::2], l[1::2])`, but note that it'll drop the last element if there are an odd number of elements in the list. Also, it's generally not a good idea to continue to ask new questions in the same question.

Comment: You could say: answerlist = [tuple(answerlist[:2]),tuple(answerlist[2:])]

Comment: list comprehensions docs can be found at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python:

```
a1 = a[0][0][0]
b1 = a[0][1][0]
c1 = a[1][0][0]
d1 = a[1][1][0]
```

this works because:

```
a[0] == ((a1, a2), (b1, b2))
```

so

```
a[0][0] == (a1, a2)
a[0][1] == (b1, b2)
```

and therefore

```
a[0][0][0] == a1
a[0][1][0] == b1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

a=[(('a1','a2'),('b1','b2')),(('c1','c2'),('d1','d2'))]
print list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x:zip(*x)[0],a)))
```

assuming your list always looks like what you showed

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Joran Beasley answer. Here is code sample using only list comprehensions, no `itertools`

```py
print list(x[0] for t in a for x in t)
```

which is almost eqvivalent to:

```
result = list()
for t in a:
    for x in t:
        result.append(x[0])
print result
```

More on list comprehensions in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

itertools has a recipe to flatten a list of nested lists one level at a time: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=flatten

you could try:

```
from itertools import chain

# the recipe...
def flatten(listOfLists):
    # "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)

a=[((1,2),(3,4)),((5,6),(7,8))]

print([list(flatten(t)) for t in a])
#   [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

print(list(flatten(flatten(a))))
#   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And then access your data as you need